# Put a symbol between every letter in a list of strings

Tags: python

How would I put ! after every character in a list

```
listOne = ["hello","world"]
```

How do I turn that into:

```
["h!e!l!l!o","w!o!r!l!d"]
```

Attempt:

```
def turn(List):
    return [i for i in (list(lambda x: "%s!" % x,listOne))]
turn(listOne)
```

Returns:

```
['hello!',"world!"]
```

Is their another way to do this besides:

```
def turn(List):
    x = ""
    for word in words:
        for letter in word:
            x += "%s!" % letter
    return x
turn(listOne)
```

I'm not a big fan of doing things like that however I do realize that may be more pythonic than what I'm trying to do which is make it as few lines as possible so. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean between each character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with the [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method, and [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> listOne = ['!'.join(i) for i in listOne]
>>> listOne
```

**Output**

```
['h!e!l!l!o', 'w!o!r!l!d']
```

Alternatively, as abarnert suggested, you can use the bulit-in [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
>>> listOne = list(map('!'.join, listOne))
>>> listOne
['h!e!l!l!o', 'w!o!r!l!d']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to revert the moving of the links up to the top, go for it; after all, it's your answer. Just keep the corrected link to `str.find` instead of `string.find`.

Comment: One more comment: Since we've got a perfectly readable callable without needing to use a `lambda` or `partial` or anything else ugly, I might use `map` here: `listOne = map('!'.join, listOne)`. But there's definitely nothing wrong with using a listcomp here.

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @alKid Why wrapping the result of `map` in `list`? Should not a list be returned anyway?

Comment: @nemo In Python 3, map returns an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: @alKid Ah, suspected that. Should have checked for myself, sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

```
listOne = ["hello","world"]

listTwo = ['!'.join([x for x in word]) for word in listOne]
```

Comment: What is the `[x for x in word]` intended to add? It does the same thing as `list(word)`, but even that isn't useful, because a string is already an iterable, and `join` already handles it just fine.

Comment: `list(word)` and `join`ing a string didn't occur to me.  Isn't it wonderful how many different ways there are to do things?

Comment: [TOOWTDI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI). Except when there's two obvious ways, of course. ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
["!".join(s) for s in ["hello", "world"]]
```

Or more specific:

```
def turn(l):
    return ["!".join(s) for s in l]
```

**Edit:** Removed wrapping of the string in `list()` as [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes every iterable 
object (those that implement `__iter__()`), and, thus strings as well. Courtesy to @alKid.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to list the element, since string is also an iterable.

Comment: @alKid Yeah, I noticed! Thanks for the heads up. Updated the answer and linked to the docs. Didn't know that `str.join` takes iterables.

Comment: @nemo: Almost _nothing_ in Python requires `list`s specifically. (`str.join` does actually have special handling for C-API-fast-sequence objects, and turns any other iterable into a `list`… but you rarely have to know that, and a string is a fast-sequence object anyway.)